# need to create a shell script or a command in unix which can do the following process(command will be preferred)

Tags: shell, dos, unix

at the following path

```
\\ncsusnasent02.na.jnj.com\its_diq_na_win_dev\PowerCenter\infa_shared\WCPIT_BIO_EDW\SrcFiles\DDDMD\DDD.CLI026.WK0933.DDDMR45.001.head
```

I have one file
DDD.CLI026.WK0933.DDDMR45.001.head

if i open this file
i get data as following(in a single line)

HEADER0101IMS HEALTHDMD Weekly   D        DD.CLI026.WK0933.DDDMR45         Centocor    DMDDRM45               W2009080210120090831125325ssnyder@us.imshealth.com
    TRAIL0101 000000000**581**                              0000000000CKSUM000002236804730

we need to copy 581(it will not be same always it gets updated everyday) from this file
and update it at following location

```
\\ncsusnasent02.na.jnj.com\its_diq_na_win_dev\PowerCenter\infa_shared\WCPIT_BIO_EDW\PrmFiles\LND\IMS_FILE_to_LND.par
```

when i open this file it has data as following

```
[WCPIT_BIO_EDW.WF:w_DDDMD_LNDG_IMS_NONRET_SALES]
$$Cust_RowCount=72648
$$Sales_RowCount=5235998
$$OuletChangeLog_RowCount=931
**$$DRM45_RowCount=581**
$$Control_RowCount=4495
$$Outl_Subcat_RowCount=105
$$Fac_Subcat_RowCount=149
```

we need to update 581 against $$DRM45_RowCount

Comment: any body plz answer the above issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that header is all on a single line (and the "**" are added by you just to emphasize what you want extracted), you can extract the number with:

```
export num=$(expr 0 + $(cat infile | cut -c137-148))
```

This extracts the number (assuming your file is specified correctly). The expression "0 + n" will strip off leading zeros. Then, using my code from your other question:

```
cat parfile | awk -va=${num} '{
    if (substr($0,1,17) == "$$DRM45_RowCount=") {
        print "$$DRM45_RowCount=" a
    } else {
        print
    }
}' > newparfile
```

Now `newparfile` should contain the value you want.

Comment: we are now shifting from unix platform to windows ...
can u plz help us in implementing it in windows......

Comment: You need Cygwin or MinGW - then you get all the UNIX utilities you need and they're far better than the standard Windows commond interpreter.

Comment: well it is out of scope...........
only thing i can do so to convert the commands fro unix to cmd

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can solve this using Windows scripting (I'm not expert in that), but usually I rather install **CygWin** and wrote a *bash/awk/sed* script for such operations. Is this acceptable for you and your situation?

Comment: no,i need to add this script in a etl tool named informatica at session level............

Comment: Hm, I don't know about this etl tool, but if you can run batch/command, you also can run shell script via cygwin for sure. This processing is kind of trivial for Linux shell's text utilities.