# Need to implement in unix following thing

Tags: unix, shell

there is one variable **var=581** 
we need to copy the value of this variable at following address(location)
and value should appear in front of **$$DRM45_RowCount**

**\ncsusnasent02.na.jnj.com\its_diq_na_win_dev\PowerCenter\infa_shared\WCPIT_BIO_EDW\PrmFiles\LND\IMS_FILE_to_LND.par**

when I open this file IMS_FILE_to_LND.par it has data as following

```
[WCPIT_BIO_EDW.WF:w_DDDMD_LNDG_IMS_NONRET_SALES]
$$Cust_RowCount=72648
$$Sales_RowCount=5235998
$$OuletChangeLog_RowCount=931
$$DRM45_RowCount=581
$$Control_RowCount=4495
$$Outl_Subcat_RowCount=105
$$Fac_Subcat_RowCount=149
```

**we need to update 581 against $$DRM45_RowCount**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to replace the value of `$$DRM45_RowCount`, you can use `awk` as follows:

```
awk -va=99 '{
    if (substr($0,1,17) == "$$DRM45_RowCount=") {
        print "$$DRM45_RowCount=" a
    } else {
        print
    }
}'
```

The `-va=99` controls is what will replace the current value (in this case it changes it to 99).

The following test command:

```
echo '[WCPIT_BIO_EDW.WF:w_DDDMD_LNDG_IMS_NONRET_SALES]
$$Cust_RowCount=72648
$$Sales_RowCount=5235998
$$OuletChangeLog_RowCount=931
$$DRM45_RowCount=581
$$Control_RowCount=4495
$$Outl_Subcat_RowCount=105
$$Fac_Subcat_RowCount=149' | awk -va=99 '{
    if (substr($0,1,17) == "$$DRM45_RowCount=") {
        print "$$DRM45_RowCount=" a
    } else {
        print
    }
}'
```

outputs:

```
[WCPIT_BIO_EDW.WF:w_DDDMD_LNDG_IMS_NONRET_SALES]
$$Cust_RowCount=72648
$$Sales_RowCount=5235998
$$OuletChangeLog_RowCount=931
$$DRM45_RowCount=99
$$Control_RowCount=4495
$$Outl_Subcat_RowCount=105
$$Fac_Subcat_RowCount=149
```

Alternatively, you could use `sed`:

```
sed 's/^$$DRM45_RowCount=.*$/$$DRM45_RowCount=99/'
```

or:

```
export a=99
sed "s/^\$\$DRM45_RowCount=.*$/\$\$DRM45_RowCount=$a/"
```

Comment: except thanks
can u plz look into the following issue.Its the main issue
link is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409565/need-to-create-a-shell-script-or-a-command-in-unix-which-can-do-the-following-pr