# how to use dos commands to do following

Tags: windows, dos

At the following location
\ncsusnasent02.na.jnj.com\its_diq_na_win_dev\PowerCenter\infa_shared\WCPIT_BIO_EDW\SrcFiles\DDDMD\DDD.CLI026.WK0933.DDDMR45.001.head

I have one file
DDD.CLI026.WK0933.DDDMR45.001.head

if i open this file
i get data as following(in a single line)

```
HEADER0101IMS HEALTHDMD Weekly   D        DD.CLI026.WK0933.DDDMR45         Centocor    DMDDRM45               W2009080210120090831125325ssnyder@us.imshealth.com      
    TRAIL0101 000000000581                         0000000000CKSUM000002236804730
```

we need to copy 581(it will not be same always it gets updated everyday) from this file

and put it in a variable

Comment: Can you please rephrase the question as it doesn't make sense?

Comment: @kane look here for exolanation:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409565/need-to-create-a-shell-script-or-a-command-in-unix-which-can-do-the-following-pr

Comment: You need to provide more information. 

Is the file in the same location and with the same name every time? How do you know which bit you need to read - is it the number after the 9th whitespace, or does it always follow "TRAIL0101", or is it always the only 12-digit number in the file, or...?

Broadly, though, this won't be possible with "pure" DOS commands. You'll need to install some GNU tools and use sed or similar. If you give us more info on what you're trying to acheive, we can help work out how to do that.

Comment: @kane HONK is right.
Dat ques was asked by me too 
 but we need to do it in DOS/windows env as per requirement........

So we need to copy required text from one text file 
and copy it at a particular location in another text file......

Comment: @vicky ..first we need to implement for this file only......
yeah we need to copy 581 of 000000000581

and paste it against a particular location in other file

Comment: @vicky.....can we do it using batch files........

Answer (score 3):

you can try the below.  It will set the field into the environment variable `id`:

```
 for /f "tokens=10" %%a IN (%1) do (
   SET id=%%a
 )
 echo %id%
```

You can pass the full path and file name into the bat as the first argument.

edit:

This simple bat will take the input from the file you specify on the commandline (param `%1`), it will use the default separators of `<space>` and `<tab>` to break the line in your file - defined in the `IN` set -  into a set of tokens.  The `"tokens=10"` param tells the processor to pass the 10th token, which turns out to be your number in question, into the `DO` block.  It is passed in as a param `%%a`.  Within the `DO` block, I simply assign that value to an environment variable `id`.  After the `for` command is complete,  I echo the value out to the console.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [the FOR command](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/for.mspx), specifically the part about the /F parameter.

I'm not certain enough about the structure of that line to even try to write the full command, but you should be able to write it yourself given that information.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm to me it looks more like the guy needs a dos substr... i.e.

```
@Echo Off

If not %1.==[]. (Cmd /V:On /C Call %0 [] %1 & GoTo :EOF)

Shift
Set MyVariable=HELLOWORLD
Set ASubStr=!MyVariable:~%1!
Echo [!ASubStr!]
```

So for example save this as test.bat  and then call "test.bat 5"  and it will echo WORLD

Google DOS Substring and work out how to parse your text variable the way you want it.